# Perfect forwarding and ambiguity of function-parameter binding

Tags: c++, c++11

I am experimenting with the perfect forwarding feature of C++11. Gnu g++ compiler reports an ambiguity issue of function-parameter binding (the error is shown after the source code below). My question is **why is it so,** as following the function-parameter binding process I don't see the ambiguity. My reasoning is as follows: call to **tf(a)** in main() binds to tf(int&) since **a** is an lvalue. Then function **tf** forwards the lvalue reference **int& a** to function **g** hence the function **void g(int &a)** should be uniquely invoked. Thus I do not see the reason for ambiguity. The error disappears when the overloaded function **g(int a)** is removed from the code. This is strange as **g(int a)** cannot be a candidate for binding with **int &a**.

Here is my code:

```
void g(int &&a)
{
  a+=30;
}

void g(int &a)
{
  a+=10;
}

void g(int a)   //existence of this function originates the ambiguity issue
{
  a+=20;
}

template<typename T>
void tf(T&& a)
{
  g(forward<T>(a));;
}

int main()
{
  int a=5;
  tf(a);
  cout<<a<<endl;
}
```

Compilation **g++ -std=c++11 perfectForwarding.cpp** reports the following **errors**:

```
perfectForwarding.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void tf(T&&) [with T = int&]’:
perfectForwarding.cpp:35:7:   required from here
perfectForwarding.cpp:24:3: error: call of overloaded ‘g(int&)’ is ambiguous
perfectForwarding.cpp:24:3: note: candidates are:
perfectForwarding.cpp:6:6: note: void g(int&&) <near match>
perfectForwarding.cpp:6:6: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘int&&’
perfectForwarding.cpp:11:6: note: void g(int&)
perfectForwarding.cpp:16:6: note: void g(int)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding on top of [Jonathan Wakely](https://stackoverflow.com/users/981959/jonathan-wakely)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18880748/1137388).

First of all, the issue has nothing to do with perfect forwarding and we can remove `tf` from the picture.

For the time being consider just this code:

```
void g(int) {}

int main() {
    int a = 5;       // a is an lvalue
    g(a);            // ok
    g(std::move(a)); // std::move(a) casts a to an rvalue and this call is also ok
}
```

This illustrates that a function that takes a parameter by value can take both lvalues and rvalues.

Now suppose we add

```
void g(int &) {}
```

then the first call, `g(a);`, becomes ambigous because `g(int &)` can take non-`const` lvalues and nothing else. The second call, `g(std::move(a))` is still ok and still calls `g(int)` because `g(int &)` can't take rvalues.

Now replace `g(int &)` with `g(int &&)`. The latter function can take non-`const` rvalues only. Hence the call `g(a)` is ok and calls `g(int)`. However, `g(std::move(a))` is now ambiguous.

At this point it becomes obvious that if we have the three overloads together, then the two calls become ambiguous. Actually, **there's no reason for having the three overloads**. Depending on the type `T`, most often we have either

1. `g(T)` or
2. `g(T&)` or
3. `g(const T&)` or
4. `g(const T&)` and `g(T&&)`.

Answer (score 7):

> This is strange as **g(int a)** cannot be a candidate for binding with **int &a**.

That's not true. If you remove the `g(int&)` overload then `g(int)` will get called. When both are declared it is ambiguous, because both are viable candidates and require no conversions.